# random HTML when I export my gridview data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I am exporting my gridview data there appears to be some random HTML code at the top and bottom of the text file. I have removed some code that I thought might be the issue but nothing is working. I dont know where this HTML is coming from at all. Here is my c# export method

```
protected void ExportTextFile(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.Buffer = true;
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "CreditFile.txt"));
  Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); //need
  HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); //need
  GridView4.AllowPaging = false; //okay
  GridView4.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF"); //okay
  for (int a = 0; a < GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; a++) //okay
  {
    GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells[a].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1"); //okay
  }
  int j = 1;
  foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in GridView4.Rows) //okay
  {
    gvrow.BackColor = Color.White;
    if (j <= GridView4.Rows.Count) {
      if (j % 2 != 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++) {
          gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
        }
      }
    }
    j++;
  }
  GridView4.RenderControl(htw);
  Response.Write(sw.ToString());
  Response.End();
}
```

here is the HTML that shows up at the top

```
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="rows" id="GridView4" style="background-color:White;border-color:#E7E7FF;border-width:1px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:#F7F7F7;background-color:#4A3C8C;font-weight:bold;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#507CD1;">AppID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#507CD1;">Credit File</th>
      <th scope="col" style="background-color:#507CD1;">CreationDate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#4A3C8C;background-color:White;">
      <td align="left" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">1017</td>
      <td align="left" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
        <div style="width: 100px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">
          <span id="GridView4_Label1_0">
```

and bottom

```
    </div>
  </td>
  <td align="left" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">11/17/2016</td>
</tr>
<tr style="color:#4A3C8C;background-color:White;">
  <td align="left">1017</td>
  <td align="left">
    <div style="width: 100px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">
      <span id="GridView4_Label1_1">
```

Comment: But.... that's what your code does explicitly. It creates an HTML file with `HtmlTextWriter ` containing a table generated from a GridView with styles explicitly specified in the rest of the code. If anything, the content type should be HTML, not text. What were you trying to generate?

Comment: when I export the gridview I want to export it as a text file, which it is doing but then how do I avoid using the HtmlTextWriter and just export the data in the gridview?

Comment: Export in what form? Besides, a grid view has no data. It uses data in containers like lists, data tables, to generate HTML tables. If you want to create a text file, just create a text file, eg with `File.CreateText` and write to it with eg `WriteLine` to write out individual elements or data rows. Or use StringBuilder's methods like `AppendLine` and `AppendFormat` to add lines to it, then send the string to the client

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET GridView Control is one among many `System.Web.UI.WebControl` the framework uses.

It has many built-in features like sorting and paging and user have little control over the html it spew out.

This lack of control over the HTML generated is the problem you are experiencing. You can do nothing about it if you are using `asp:GridView`

For better control over generated HTML, use `asp:ListView`.

---

If you want to copy this as a table to `txt` without any extra html, you will have to iterate through the header-row and collection of data-row manually.

Pseudo Code

```
GridView4.AllowPaging = false;
var tableHtml = "<table>";
//header code
tableHtml += "<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>";
for (int a = 0; a < GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; a++) //okay
{
  tableHtml += "<td style='background-color:#507CD1'>" + GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells[a].Text + "</td>";
}
tableHtml += "</tr>";
//rows code
//TODO: ...
tableHtml += "</table>";
```